# how to create insert stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure and i am getting an error code.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 12

I'm not the greatest with MYSQL and I'm unsure where to even look to figure the problem out.

```
Create Procedure Sp_insertCustomer(
    IN Customer_id VARCHAR(20) ,
    IN UserName VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Fname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Lname VARCHAR(20), 
    IN Dob Date, 
    IN Address VARCHAR(250),
    IN Phone INT,
    IN Email VARCHAR(250), 
    IN Ss VARCHAR(9) )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Customer (Cusomter_id,UserName,Fname,Lname,Dob,Address,Phone,Email,Ss)       
VALUES (in_Customer_id ,in_UserName , in_Fname , in_Lname , in_Dob , in_Address , in_Phone , in_Email , in_Ss);
END
```

Comment: The variables inside the INSERT `VALUES` section do not match your in Parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your parameters and values in insert statement are different: 
Customer_id  is parameter  and in_Customer_id  in insert statement

2) add delimeters

DELIMITER $$

< your procedure >

END$$           --- instead your END

DELIMITER ;

Comment: so instead of in_Customer_id it should just be Customer_id?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed the parameters names. Also you are not need to specify IN for params.

```
DELIMITER $$
Create Procedure Sp_insertCustomer(
Customer_id VARCHAR(20) ,
UserName VARCHAR(20), 
Fname VARCHAR(20), 
Lname VARCHAR(20), 
Dob Date, 
Address VARCHAR(250),
Phone INT,
Email VARCHAR(250), 
Ss VARCHAR(9) )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Customer (Cusomter_id, UserName, Fname, Lname, Dob, Address, Phone, Email, Ss) 
VALUES (Customer_id, UserName, Fname, Lname, Dob, Address, Phone, Email, Ss);
END$$
```